# Add border without changing height of block

Tags: html, css

I have some table, based on `div`s. When table row is hovered, i want to add borders to the top and bottom of it. But in spite of `box-sizing: border-box`, my block becomes 2 pixels bigger. Row can't have fixed height.

Here is example: https://jsfiddle.net/j4nwdju6/

I can't just add invisible or transparent borders, because it will spawn whitespaces between rows.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Computed height remains constant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can offset this by adjusting the top & bottom margins on the hovered state:

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4nwdju6/3/)

```
.row:hover {
    background: yellow;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin: -1px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i need.

Answer (score 2):

You may add a transparent border in `.row` like this

```
.row {    
display: flex;
border-top: 1px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

This will not affect the height of div on hover.

**UPDATE**

To remove white space b/w rows add `margin-top:-2px` . Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4nwdju6/5/).

Comment: As i said in my question, `I can't just add invisible or transparent borders, because it will spawn whitespaces between rows.`.

Answer (score 1):

Add border to your rows so that it wont jump while hovering

```
.row {    
    display: flex;
    border:1px solid white;
}
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/j4nwdju6/1/

Comment: As i said in my question, `I can't just add invisible or transparent borders, because it will spawn whitespaces between rows.`.

Comment: Just said the same thing @Efog! Got there before me :)

Answer (score 1):

A really simple hack would be to add `margin-top: -2px;` to the `:hover` styles, so that the position doesn't change: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4nwdju6/2/).

Comment: Yeah, but now text in rows is moving when hovered. I can do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/j4nwdju6/4/ but it will be really dirty hack.

Comment: @dwreck's answer is correct: adjusting it to `margin: -1 0;` will solve that problem :)